# Graph.facebook.com not returning shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to save facebook share count (the number shown next to facebook like button) in my database. There is a facebook url for that purpose as follows:

graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Output that i get for this url is as follows:

"id": "http://www.google.com",
"shares": 10098203,
"comments": 941

However when I noticed that for some URLs this does not work properly. My url has querystring id. I am passing encoded url string which works fine for some urls. But for some urls it does not return "shares" property at all.

I don't want users to log in to facebook. I would prefer to use the graph url as shown above. 
Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

the number of shares returned by graph api end point is **not** the exact number of likes. but the sum of

- The number of likes of this URL The number of shares of this URL  (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL
- The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.

also for urls not in the index , it won't return the share count .

---

**Edit:** thanks @Tobi

If your app can access api v2.0 . FQL can provide you with similar details , [link_stat  docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)

```
SELECT ... FROM link_stat WHERE url = ...
```

---

**Edit : going to be deprecated on April 30th 2015**

this is another facebook api end point which will return you all the data about the url, try this.

```
Facebook: https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=%%URL%%&format=json
```

**example**:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://google.com&format=json

[
    {
    url: "http://google.com",
    normalized_url: "http://www.google.com/",
    share_count: 6712940,
    like_count: 1573962,
    comment_count: 1811401,
    total_count: 10098303,
    click_count: 265614,
    comments_fbid: 383926826594,
    commentsbox_count: 10118
    }
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this shows 0 for everything where in fact there are 4 to 5 shares/like in total.

Comment: @yatz please share a sample url :)

Comment: Great. If you can use a v2.0 app, FQL (which is usable until August 7th 2016) would give you similar details as the old API, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/